# Matlab: How to get proper yticklabel

Tags: matlab

I am plotting some three column vectors as a function of SNR using **semilogy**. I would like to keep the Y-ticklabel at 0.1, 1, 5. Could someone please help me?

My attempt:

```
SNR = [50 100 200 400];
RMS_SKL_Conv        = [2.6784   1.6988  1.1549  0.8807];
RMS_SKL_Spatial     = [0.9058   0.619   0.4886  0.4432];
RMS_SKL_Spatial_FAEC= [0.2184   0.1325  0.1197  0.1281];

figure(2);
semilogy(SNR, RMS_SKL_Conv, '*-r', SNR, RMS_SKL_Spatial, '*-b', SNR, RMS_SKL_Spatial_FAEC, 'o-k', 'LineWidth', 3, 'MarkerSize', 15);
legend({'Conventional W/O FAE Correction','Spatial W/O FAE Correction', 'Spatial with FAE Correction'},'FontSize', 20, 'FontName', 'Times new roman', 'FontWeight','bold');
set(gca,'YTickMode','manual')
set(gca,'ytick',[10^-1 10^0 4])
```

Also, I notice that **ticklabel** gets changed by re-sizing.  Could someone please explain me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SNR = [50 100 200 400];
RMS_SKL_Conv        = [2.6784   1.6988  1.1549  0.8807];
RMS_SKL_Spatial     = [0.9058   0.619   0.4886  0.4432];
RMS_SKL_Spatial_FAEC= [0.2184   0.1325  0.1197  0.1281];

figure(2);
semilogy(SNR, RMS_SKL_Conv, '*-r', SNR, RMS_SKL_Spatial, '*-b', SNR, RMS_SKL_Spatial_FAEC, 'o-k', 'LineWidth', 3, 'MarkerSize', 15);
legend({'Conventional W/O FAE Correction','Spatial W/O FAE Correction', 'Spatial with FAE Correction'},'FontSize', 20, 'FontName', 'Times new roman', 'FontWeight','bold');


ylim([0 5])
set(gca,'YTick',[0.2  1 5])
```